# Are application layer protocols part of system utilities?

Tags: networking, system

Are applications layer protocols like dhcp, http, dns, ftp, nfs, smb, etc part of system utilities like ls, cp, chmod, rm, mv, etc?

Comment: DNS and DHCP are protocols...

Comment: but not network procol in the sense of TCP or ethernet. thought the question is very unclear

Comment: Anyway, I think what the user is  asking is just if these protocols, utilities or whatever they are, are integrated into the core-utils or are just installed by default but aren't part of the core system. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Close-voters: This is a question about system utilities in Ubuntu, which I have answered in an Ubuntu context, addressing the utilities mentioned. It's hard to see a reason to consider this unclear. *Concepts are often unclear in people's minds, which is one reason to ask questions.* That's not the kind of unclarity we close for. The confusion in this question--as well as *what*'s being sought--is expressed quite clearly. Although I'm tempted to edit the title to "What's the relationship between system utilities and application-layer protocols?", I think the current wording is more accessible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### What it Means to Be a Protocol

A protocol is a rule (or collection of rules) about how information is communicated. An [application-layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_layer) protocol describes how programs and services communicate on top of underlying protocols of "lower" layers. These lower layers--such as the [transport layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_layer)--describe how communication in general takes place, including how higher-layer communication is packaged.

That is a very general summary, and there is more than one layered model of networking. How many layers there are, even, is determined by which model one chooses to use to describe how networking works.

Together, the layers compose a suite, such as the [Internet protocol suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP_model), that describes how a working system (that we think of as "a network") is to function.

The key point is that a protocol is a rule or description for how something is supposed to work. Therefore a protocol is not "part" of a program in any ordinary sense of "part." However, a program can *implement* an application layer protocol. This means it is written to carry out the sort of communication specified in the protocol, in a way that complies with the protocol.

(Sometimes programs are non-compliant, too, varying from the requirements of a protocol. Often this is a shortcoming--sometimes it is intentional, when the protocol doesn't fit the needs of users or developers.)

#### Programs that Implement Application-Layer Protocols

DHCP is implemented by DHCP servers and DHCP clients. HTTP is implemented by [web servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server) (like Apache), web browsers, [crawlers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler), and (together with other protocols) most [download managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Download_manager). The browsers, crawlers, and download managers are HTTP clients. SMB on Ubuntu is implemented by Samba, which has client and server components.

Application-layer protocols rest on top of lower level layers that provide a client-server model. Application-layer protocols use this model; you'll notice I've talked about clients and servers for all the above examples.

Sometimes a program has the same name as a protocol it implemented. For example, most operating systems including Ubuntu have an FTP client called `ftp`. Note that this is just an FTP client; an FTP server executable is usually called `ftpd` (`d` for ["daemon"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29)). A daemon is a service that runs in the background, and many server programs are daemons. It's common for the daemon that implements protocol "FooBar" to be called `foobard`. For example, web server executables are commonly named `httpd`.

#### Core File Utilities Don't Themselves Implement Application-Layer Protocols

So you may be wondering if *file utilities* like `ls`, `cp`, `chmod`, `rm`, and `mv` **implement** any application-layer protocols. The answer is that **they do not.**

Using any of those file utilities may cause network communication to occur, if they access files or directory information across a network. For example, if you have mounted an NFS (or SMB) share, and you use `ls` to list the contents of a remote folder, network communication is happening. But those file utilities don't take care of that network communication. Instead, the NFS client (or SMB) client carries out that communication. Typically, a file utility like `ls` or `chmod` will work exactly the same as when accessing local files.

Comment: It is said that transport, internet and network access layer protocols are part of kernel. Thus, it lets me to conclude that application layer protocols are on user level/space, not kernel, which is on the same level of system utilities, applications and library functions. Is that correct? If yes, where do those application layer protocols reside on Ubuntu? Thanks.